# Display value in second dropdownlist depending on what I select in the first dropdownlist

Tags: c#, forms, drop-down-menu

[image: facilitytable]

[image: FAC_TYPE]
[image: FAC_CODE]

I have this table called FACILITIES. If i select a option on FAC_TYPE dropdownlist, I want the FAC_CODE dropdownlist to display the FAC_CODE that belong to the FAC_TYPE. For now my FAC_CODE dropdownlist displays every data in the FAC_CODE field. What I want is the second dropdownlist to be always empty and etc, If i select meeting in first dropdownlist, L335 and L336 will only display in the FAC_CODE dropdownlist. Then if I select tutorial, L337 will only display in the FAC_CODE dropdownlist. Help

```
public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_TYPE from FACILITIES", con);  
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacilityType.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_TYPE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
                        // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacilityType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacilityType.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITIES", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacility.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacility.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacility.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
        }


    }
}
```

followed sanjay code. Nothing is displayed on second dropdownlist whatever choices i click on first dropdownlist.

[image: problem]

```
public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_TYPE from FACILITIES", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacilityType.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_TYPE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacilityType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacilityType.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
        }
    }


    protected void ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITIES where FAC_TYPE='" + ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

        ddlFacility.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        // to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlFacility.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlFacility.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
    }
}
```

Comment: try ajax cascading dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the second dropdown "ddlFacility" with  onselectedchange event of dropdown ddlFacilityType

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFacilityType" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">   



protected void ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITIES where FAC_TYPE='"+ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString()+"'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacility.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacility.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacility.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist


}
```

Comment: still cannot work. I edited the code and posted my image above. @sanjay bhansali

Comment: Selected change events is fired ? Please debug the code. wheneve you change ddlFacilityType value then selected change event must fire.check dropdown  you assign event  onselectedindexchanged="ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: Please add AutoPostBack="true" property in dropdown ddlFacilityType  for postback